# Minimum Items in Cart for Checkout

Tags: ubercart

I am working in Drupal 7 in Ubercart 3, and I am looking for a way to set a minimum on the number of items that a user can have before being able to start the checkout process.

Is there a module out there that handles this need?

Answer (score 1):

There is [Ubercart Product Minimum & Maximum](http://drupal.org/project/uc_product_minmax)

> Adds minimum, maximum and order in multiples limits on products.
>   Checks that the quantity selected matches the limits during both Add
>   To Cart and Checkout actions. Quantity checks are disabled when
>   product is added to the cart as part of a product kit.

If you want to do it with code this is one way to do that.

You can make use of [hook_add_to_cart](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/hook_add_to_cart) to get the product add event.

To get the number of items use [uc_cart_get_contents](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/uc_cart_get_contents)

The ides is

```
function <modulename>_add_to_cart($nid, $qty, $data) {
  $items = uc_cart_get_contents();
// Display a message if the cart has more than 5 products.
  $item_count = count($items);
  if ($item_count < 5) {
    drupal_set_message('Your cart Should contains more than 5 products to checkout !');
    // drupal_goto to product listing page
  }
  return $result;
}
```